# Why is Materialize.css not working as expected?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, bower, materialize

I am trying to implement a Materialize.css navbar that should look like this:

[image]

I have the following HTML as provided by their example:

```
<div>
    <div class="navbar-fixed">
        <nav>
            <div class="nav-wrapper">
                <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
                <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                    <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
                    <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

However in both IE 11 and Chrome it looks like this (note the blue hover colour and underline, same for the "Logo" text except the underline is white):

[image]

And when I make the window smaller the menu vanishes completely instead of turning into a menu on the left like their example. This is what mine looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For turn your menu into a left menu on mobile, you have to use a `navbar` with mobile collapse (http://materializecss.com/navbar.html#mobile-collapse).
Change your HTML markup to:

```
<div>
    <div class="navbar-fixed">
        <nav>
            <div class="nav-wrapper">
                <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
                <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
                <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                    <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
                    <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
                    <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
                    <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

And use this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. It is actually because the default ASP.NET MVC 5 template uses Bootstrap. Bootstrap breaks the bar, removing Bootstrap resolves the issue.